# Counts of particular strings in columns

Tags: r

I want to count the number of "Agree" and "Disagree" in each column. ALl I have done so far is some recoding of the data, but how do I get the counts for each column. I have tried summarise_all but this has not worked. I am trying to work in dplyr

```
new<-subjects1%>%
  filter(Qx1_mod1=='Health, Public Services and Care')%>%
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "Strongly agree", "Agree")))%>%
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "Strongly disagree", "Disagree")))%>%
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "Neither agree nor disagree", "Neither")))
```

Comment: A little bit of sample data would help. Probably the easiest solution is to convert to a long format, but it's hard to know for sure, and hard to demonstrate, without an idea of what your data looks like.

Comment: I see you've asked a few R questions on here where you've been asked to share data. Please make it a habit when asking questions---it makes it much easier and faster to help. If you don't share data, we just end up asking you to share data, which wastes time for everyone. [This FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) is full of resources for creating a reproducible example. We just need enough data to illustrate the problem and get a sense for your data structure. `dput(subjects1[1:10, 1:5])` is a great way to share the first 10 rows of the first 5 columns, which is probably plenty.

Comment: @Gregor is right. You see that you have received a couple of very different solutions since nobody knows how your actual data looks like and everyone seems to imagine something else it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("", "somewhat agree", "agree"),
  col2 = c("", "I agree", "agree"),
  col3 = c("agree", "agree", "agree"),
  col4 = c("disagree", "agree, Agree", "agree, agree"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

pattern <- "(^a| a)gree"
res <- colSums(apply(df, 2, function(x, s = pattern) grepl(s, x, ignore.case = TRUE)))

> res
# col1 col2 col3 col4 
#   2    2    3    2
```

Comment: why use `"(^a| a)gree"` and not just "agree"? Could you explain?

Comment: I do not want to count `disagree` as `agree`

Comment: Good thinking. I altered my pattern as well. But I prefer word boundaries (`\\b`).

Answer (score 0):

A simple setup would be something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
subjects1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("", "", "agree"),
  col2 = c("", "agree", "agree"),
  col3 = c("agree", "agree", "agree"),
  col4 = c("agree", "agree, agree", "agree, agree"),
  col5 = c("disagree", "agree, Agree", "Neither")
)

subjects1 %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) str_count(x,  regex(pattern = "\\bagree\\b", ignore_case = TRUE))) %>%
  colSums()
#> col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
#>    1    2    3    5    2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a simple frequency cross-table, you can always use `table` like this:

```
col_1 <- c("Agree","Agree","Disagree","Neither","Disagree", "Agree")
col_2 <- c("Neither","Neither","Disagree","Neither","Disagree", "Agree")

data.frame(col_1,col_2) %>%
  gather(columns,values) %>%
  table()

# output 
columns Agree Disagree Neither
  col_1     3        2       1
  col_2     1        2       3
```